# carrierwave does not save content_type on Uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have followed the instructions from https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#setting-the-content-type

so I got:

```
require 'carrierwave/processing/mime_types'
class AssetFileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type
  ...
```

but after a file upload the content_type is not updated.

I have a AssetInfo model with a uploader AssetFileUploader mounted on

```
:file attribute
class AssetInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :file, AssetFileUploader
...
```

The params contain:

```
... "file"=># @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"asset[asset_info_attributes][file]\"; filename=\"img.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"> ...
```

After the file upload I try in the console:

> AssetInfo.last.file.file
>   => < CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x34b1c @original_filename=nil @content_type=nil @file="/home/reea/projects/ruby/learning_cms/public/uploads/asset_info/file/20/img.jpg">
>
> AssetInfo.last.file.file.content_type
>   => nil

Comment: after updating the app to work with Amazon S3, the content type is saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carrierewave says they will deprecate this feature in the future and advise to use the `Carrierwave::SanitizedFile` instead

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/processing/mime_types.rb

There's also an override method attached to this method

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/processing/mime_types.rb#L56

Maybe that can give you direction.